# Multer file upload empty object for req.body and undefined for req.file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

I had posted earlier about the issue with file upload using multer. I am trying it in the mern stack. I am not still able to solve it though I had tried many ways. I have both body-parser and multer used in my app. In the index.js I have the following order of code:

```
    const express=require('express')
    const app=express()
    const route=require('./router/route')
    const db=require('./models/db')
    const cors=require('cors')
    const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    const path=require('path')
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./public/")));
    app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:3000'}))
    app.use('/blog',route)
    app.listen(4000,()=>{
      console.log('listening on port 4000')
    })
```

The user uploads the file using the form and the state of the fields are set using the react hooks.

```
 const Addimage=()=> {

const [file, setfile] = useState('')
const {addImage}=useContext(Globalcontext)

const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
e.preventDefault()
const formData = new FormData()
formData.set('file', file[0])
// console.log([...formData])

const addedValue={
   formData
}

addImage(addedValue)

setfile('')
}
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="mfile" onChange={(e)=>{setfile(e.target.files)}} />
                <button type='submit' value='submit'>Add Image</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Addimage
```

I had added the header in the axios post request but it was not working so, I tried by adding the multipart/form-data to the form itself. The post request is sent as following:

```
    function addImage(imagedetail){
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/blog/upload',imagedetail).then(res=>{
    dispatch({
      type:'ADD_IMAGE',
      payload:res.data
    })
    
  }).catch(error=>{ 
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

This is what I have in the server side:

```
   exports.addImage=(req,res)=>{
   if(req.file){
       console.log('success')
   }
   else{
       console.log('upload a file')
   }
   console.log(req.file)

   }
```

I have set the multer middleware in the route as:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads",
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,"IMAGE-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

const upload=multer({
    storage:storage
})
router.route('/upload',upload.single('mfile')).post(addImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

to this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false }));
```

I think this will help you to solve your problem.